# Firefox applying styling to script block

Tags: firefox

I have simplified a problem I faced in Firefox (the original code is generated by server side controls). Open the following snippet in IE and in Firefox:

```
<html>
<style>
    .AllInline, .AllInline * { display: inline; }
</style>
<span class="AllInline">
    Test
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- var obj = {}; //-->
    </script>
</span>
</html>
```

In IE, I get:
Test
While in Firefox, I get:
Test `<!-- var obj = {}; //-->`

The content of the script block becomes visible somehow.

I was not expecting the styling rules to be applied to script blocks (can't really see a reason why one would want this either).

Would anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: How exactly does it behave in Firefox?

Comment: I have added the results I get.

Comment: Chrome behaves the same as FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base`, `basefont`, `datalist`, `head`, `meta`, `script`, `style`, `title`, `noembed` and `param` tags are hidden by the simple expedient of setting `display: none;` in `html.css` (which is a UA stylesheet). So they are subject to being unhidden by page CSS such as your example. `area` on the other hand has `display: none ! important;` because it has special internal handling (the image effectively owns the area).

Answer (score 0):

Don't put JavaScript there. Insert it just before `</body></html>`.

Test your HTMl in the [Echochamber](http://echo.yellosoft.us/).

Comment: This is only a short reproducing sample. I would not put the js here either if I was writing it. This comes from a cross fire between styling and what a DevExpress control rendered.

Answer (score 0):

fascinating bug!

you can add `.AllInline script {display: none;}` to your css to hide it.

Comment: Removing the second selector .AllInline * also works. Just still don't understand why anyone would want this...